# After ajax submit, the message is repeated

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

When I run submit, an alert message occurs as many times as you send it before you reload.

For example.

first run submit occur success message

not refresh second run submit two repeat occurs success message

not refresh third run submit three repeat occurs success message

...

not refresh n run submit n repeat occurs success message

Why does it run like this?
How can I solve this problem?

My code is as follows.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#my_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
                var p_index = $(e.relatedTarget).data('p_index');
                $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="p_index"]').val(p_index);

                $("button#submit").click(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        async: false,
                        url: "../receipt/send.php",
                        data: $('form.send_p_index').serialize(),
                        success: function(data) {
                            alert("success")
                            $("#send_p_index")[0].reset()
                            $("#my_modal").modal('hide');
                        },
                        error: function() {
                            alert("Error");
                        }
                    });
                });

            });
        }
```

Comment: Answer is simple, because you are hooking the click event everytime you open/show the the modal. I suggest you to move the button submit click hook outside the modal show. so it only hook once. To Prove what I said, you can check by https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_event_listeners on FF or https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/05/get-and-debug-event-listeners for chrome. For best debugging web, always use firefox.

Comment: also, nothing to do with your issue, but `async: false` won't work for much longer - and there really isn't any need to do synchronous requests in a click handler

Comment: @BenyaminLimanto *always use firefox* - truer words were never written

Comment: @BenyaminLimanto Thanks. your answer is modal move external?

Comment: @BenyaminLimanto
I Solved it. answer is 
 $("button#submit").click(function() { ->    $("button#submit").one("click", function(e){ change

Comment: @Bravo
I Solved it. answer is $("button#submit").click(function() { -> $("button#submit").one("click", function(e){ change

Comment: I didn't actually care, the first comment covered all your issues, I just pointed out that `async:false` is deperecated

Comment: @전준휘 Yes.. you should put it outside the hook. Well done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WRONG**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#my_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
                var p_index = $(e.relatedTarget).data('p_index');
                $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="p_index"]').val(p_index);

                $("button#submit").click(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        async: false,
                        url: "../receipt/send.php",
                        data: $('form.send_p_index').serialize(),
                        success: function(data) {
                            alert("success")
                            $("#send_p_index")[0].reset()
                            $("#my_modal").modal('hide');
                        },
                        error: function() {
                            alert("Error");
                        }
                    });
                });

            });
        }
```

**CORRECT**: **Put this outside of modal.shown** because every time the modal shown, it will write a submit function that repeats as many as it shown.

```
 $(document).on('click', 'button#submit', function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        async: false,
                        url: "../receipt/send.php",
                        data: $('form.send_p_index').serialize(),
                        success: function(data) {
                            alert("success")
                            $("#send_p_index")[0].reset()
                            $("#my_modal").modal('hide');
                        },
                        error: function() {
                            alert("Error");
                        }
                    });
});
```